# OpenTok Signalling for Sending Files

Tags: opentok, tokbox

Does anyone know if OpenToks `sendSignal()` method is peer to peer? Or does it get routed through OpenTok's servers? We are looking to send image and video files P2P, but the signaling method seems a bit slower than webRTC's native data channel. I'm wondering if there is something extra happening under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, you should be able to send to a specific end: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Session.html#signal. What you need to do is to specify a Connection object.

Comment: Yeah I looked into this. It doesn't seem to be the native WebRTC data channel which is P2P.

The signalling you linked here seems to use their own implementation called 'Rumor' that is not P2P http://www.tokbox.com/blog/webrtc-and-signaling-what-two-years-has-taught-us/